# How to uninstall a plugin and all its created files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-bukkit

*This is a general question and not targeted at specific plugins - please keep it that way.*

I installed several Bukkit plugins (copied jars to the plugins folder).

I ran the server and some folders were created under the plugins folder.

I decided to uninstall one of the plugins. I know what jars to delete and I want to delete the folders it created as well.

**Which folders were created by which plugin?**

Comment: Are you sure it was the plugins that created the folders? It may be that the plugins did not create any folders. Usually the minecraft server base is what creates the folder structure and appropriate files.

Comment: These are sub-folders under the plugins folder. They were created only after installing the plugins (copied jars to to the plugins folder)

Comment: I'll rephrase the question to discuss folders specifically found under the plugins folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In the general case*, the best way to work it out is get a separate, blank installation and add the mod you want to remove. See what the side-effects are (what files are created) when you add that mod. Then go to your proper installation and remove those files.

Comment: Sounds like a solution. I'll wait for some more answers before I accept this.

Comment: What if two plugins use the same folder?

Comment: @kilaka Then check every *file* created by the mod, delete the corresponding files, and then any folders that are empty.

Comment: You also might check the specific plugin documentation because 9/10 times they note in the documentation what files that plugin/mod makes.

Answer (score 0):

So this is Bukkit plugins? The general rule for the plugins is that they each have a folder that is their name. Two plugins will not use the same folder, unless they have the same name, which is highly unlikely, and I don't even think it is possible. So, by simply deleting the plugin .jar file and the folder with the same name, you will have removed the plugin.

If you cannot find a folder with the same name as your plugin, look for one with a similar name. If you are still unable to find the folder for it, look at fredley's suggestion: try creating a new Bukkit server on your computer, add the plugin in question, and find what files and folders it creates. These are the files that you want to delete. If you accidentally delete a folder, just restore it from the Recycle Bin or Trash.

If you **still** cannot figure out which folder to delete, just don't delete any. This will cause no harm, all of the plugins will work as they used to, and there will be no risk of accidentally deleting a folder that is needed for another plugin.

Comment: Plugin<->folder correlation is not always the case. For example, installing EssentialsGroupManager.jar creates the folder 'GroupManager' and not 'EssentialsGroupManager'.

Comment: Also, counting on a convention will always have exceptions.